# Windows 7 sometimes restarting on boot

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 is ok, my PC is ok, but together they sometimes have a quarrel when waking up.

Simply put, my PC always boots cleanly into Windows XP, but 3 times out of 10 it crashes when booting into Windows 7 (don't ask me why I still linger with an XP boot).

Not even a BSOD, W7 just reboots and goes through the F8 routine, with countdown to normal startup.
Ok, once you get used to making coffee before you start working, it really is no problem.
After two or three restarts W7 actually powers up, and then it keeps working like sunshine.

But still...

At first I thought it had to be a problem with the hardware, considering the randomness of it.
Removed all unnecessary HW, just leaving the boot disk and a keyboard.
Problem remained.
Bought a heavy duty 700 Watt supply, just in case, and renewed all my cables.
Still to no effect.
Updated the BIOS, even swapped the HDD with a brand new one and re-installed Windows 7.

That worked.
For a day.
Then the problem was back.

Tomorrow I will buy a new MoBo and a new processor.
But if the problem keeps recurring, should I consult a witchdoctor?
Or has anybody here got a clue of what is going on?

Thank you in advance,

Aunt Grace